# SQL Server - REPLACE - Matching string with old substring edits entire field?

Tags: sql-server

I recently had a request come through to remove some Agent names from the guest surname field in a client's database.

Eg. `'John Smith -Wotif'`

When testing using the following UPDATE statement, the entire field was wiped rather than just the specific string.

```
UPDATE GUEST
SET SURNAME = REPLACE(' -Wotif',' -Wotif','')
WHERE SURNAME LIKE '% -Wotif'
```

I've since found that simply using the column name as the matching string will allow the full statement to work (even if already specified in the SET section), but I can't work out where the logic of the original statement effectively says 'wipe these fields entirely'.

Unless specified otherwise, surely the `''` replacement only applies to the value contained within the substring, regardless of whether the string and substring match?

Comment: Were you really setting the surname to `REPLACE(' -Wotif',' -Wotif','')` instead of `REPLACE(SURNAME,' -Wotif','')`? If so, the answer should be obviously - you were setting the surname to be blank because that's what the former replace returns...

Comment: Whatever is outside of the string should remain, regardless.
Where does the string specify that the 'Smith' component be replaced?

Comment: I've effectively said:
(Find this string,
Replace this section,
With this)

NOT

(Find this string,
Replace the entire field,
With this)

Comment: "Where does the string specify that the 'Smith' component be replaced?" You were doing that by setting the surname. `SET SURNAME = X` means you set the entire field to be X. Substituting `REPLACE(SURNAME, ' -Wotif', '')` for X would do what you want, yes, because you'd be replacing the _string pattern_ ' -Wotif' in the _string expression_ surname with ''. But substituting `REPLACE(' -Wotif',' -Wotif','')` for X means you're replacing the _string pattern_ ' -Wotif' in the _string expression_ ' -Wotif', which just so happens to be the entire string expression, with ''.

Comment: Ok, I see where it's applied the new string.
Seems like REPLACE shouldn't even be able to be used in conjunction with SET.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in the `REPLACE` function is the full string that you want to search. So you should be referencing the `SURNAME` field rather than specifying part of the string.

`REPLACE(SURNAME,' -Wotif','')`

Comment: This is where the documentation I was referencing for REPLACE was not specific to usage with SET.

As it turns out, when used with SET, the first argument sets the column values as the string value entered.

As a SELECT statement, REPLACE uses the 3 arguments as (find,specify,replace).
As a SET statement, the arguments are (set,find,replace)

Answer (score 0):

**You update SQL command should be like this -**

```
UPDATE GUEST 
SET SURNAME = REPLACE(SURNAME, 'FindValue' , 'ReplaceWithValue') 
WHERE SURNAME LIKE '% -Wotif'
```

**If you want to find & replace '-Wotif' with blank, then update command should be like below-**

```
UPDATE GUEST 
SET SURNAME = REPLACE(SURNAME, '-Wotif' , '') 
WHERE SURNAME LIKE '% -Wotif'
```